# Difference between two time items

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out a way to find time lag between a consecutive pair of items in this list.

```
L1=[['8/1/2000', '0:00:16'],
    ['8/1/2008', '0:23:09'],
    ['8/2/2008', '12:32:16'],
    ['8/2/2008', '0:38:29']]
```

so the output would look like the difference between 1 and 2 = 0:22:53 but the difference between 2 and 3 would like 24 hours +/- difference and not just 0:06:58. Hopes this makes sense. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `L1` line would generate a SyntaxError.  Are the elements actually strings?  If so, do they look like `'8/1/2000,0:00:16'` or `'8/1/2000','0:00:16'`?

Comment: I have assumed they're strings and edited accordingly. Let me know or feel free to roll back if I did so incorrectly.

Comment: How did you get 0:06:58 between 2 and 3? Or is that what "time lag" means (I'm not too clear what "time lag" is)

Comment: Sorry, I realized I made a mistake when I did them on excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this seems to be a bit of a hit-and-run question, I'll simply point you in the direction of the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) module, give an example, and leave the rest to you.

First, we'll turn your strings (or what we've assumed were strings) into datetime objects:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> L1 = [['8/1/2000', '0:00:16'], ['8/1/2008', '0:23:09'], ['8/2/2008', '12:32:16'], ['8/2/2008', '0:38:29']]
>>> d1 = [datetime.strptime(' '.join(dt), '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') for dt in L1]
>>> d1
[datetime.datetime(2000, 8, 1, 0, 0, 16), datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 1, 0, 23, 9), datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 2, 12, 32, 16), datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 2, 0, 38, 29)]
>>> for d in d1:
...     print(d)
...     
2000-08-01 00:00:16
2008-08-01 00:23:09
2008-08-02 12:32:16
2008-08-02 00:38:29
```

and these we can simply subtract, producing timedelta objects:

```
>>> diffs = [y-x for x,y in zip(d1, d1[1:])]
>>> diffs
[datetime.timedelta(2922, 1373), datetime.timedelta(1, 43747), datetime.timedelta(-1, 43573)]
>>> for diff in diffs:
...     print(diff)
...     
2922 days, 0:22:53
1 day, 12:09:07
-1 day, 12:06:13
```

Comment: I was wondering why the first difference gives 2922 days shouldn't it give like 0 days difference since the 1 and 2 in the list have the same dates

Comment: @mparida: no, they don't.  One is 2000, the other is 2008.  (PS: Python is zero-indexed -- the first element in a list is `somelist[0]` -- so it's better to say "0th" and "1st".)

Comment: I completely missed that my bad. Thanks DSM